# RestAPI and Front-End on the same port in Docker

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, docker, digital-ocean

I have created new droplet on DigitalOcean and installed Docker. I have two containers, one with my **NodeJS** app = RestAPI **on port 8080**, and second with **Nginx** that basically expose my static html files (with AngularJS) **on port 80**.

But now, I want to start making requests from my Front-End AngularJS app to the NodeJS app but via **port 80**. Like:

```
$http({
method: 'GET',
url: '/api/myapi'
```

Problem: two Docker containers can't use the same port (80 in this case).

How I can expose RestAPI and Nginx WEB server on the same port and same domain ?

The idea is to making requests from AngularJS to own domain and same port.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to link your NodeJS container with Nginx container and map port `8080` from NodeJS to Nginx. <s>You also need to share the NodeJS files with Nginx container by mounting a volume from NodeJS container to Nginx.</s>

Then create an Nginx upstream on port `8080` so that it can proxy requests to that port. Next add rules to Nginx config so that when any static file is requested, nginx serves it. But for any non-static request, pass the request to the upstream.